# What is is called when you count the letters in an acronym, name or word with an ordinal multiplier?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, numbers

In English, we frequently look at an acronym and name multiple repeated letters using an ordinal multiplier.

For example:

> Automobile Association of America - **AAA** is read as ***Triple-A***.
>   Abdominal Aortic Aneurysm - **AAA** is read as ***Triple-A***
>   National Association for the Advancement of Colored People - **NAACP** is read as N ***Double-A*** CP
>   **Aamco** Transmission Repair - Read in their ad copy ***Double-A MCO***
>   **AAA** or **AA** Battery - ***Triple-A*** or ***Double-A*** Battery respectively

Is there a phrase or word for this phenomenon?

Comment: No, but feel free to make one up if you think we need it. Greek is always good.

Comment: @JohnLawler It seems strange that there is no name for the phenomenon.

Comment: It's not a phenomenon; it's just a way of talking about writing. Since writing is itself arbitrary, and represents so little of language, linguists don't bother inventing terminology for all its little crochets.

Comment: *AAA* is actually harder to say that *triple A*; the speaking of *eɪ-jeɪ-jeɪ* takes longer and is slightly more taxing. I'm surprised as well that there is no name for this substitution.

Comment: @medica That is a great observation, I hadn't thought about that!  I'm sure you know the GSW vs. Gun Shot Wound phenomenon, though.  3 syllables vs. 4.  Abbreviation mania is rampant in medicine.

Comment: @DavidM - *that*, though, is due to charting. When we had to *write* everything out, it was much easier to write, *CC (x); pt - 33yo BM px w/ GSW RLE.* It was *necessary*. This phenomenon is not; it's done for comfort. It has something to do with whatever term describes making sounds with the oropharynx. I'm sure someone knows this.

Comment: @medica I know.  I had an ex-GF who used to point out that we were being illogical in saying GSW.  It used to annoy me.  I had an attending in Med School who had us write an entire admission in abbreviations.  LOL in NAD PAFO.  PE WNL.  PMH NC.  Etc. - PAFO - Pissed and Fell Over . . .;-)

Comment: Here in Bellingham, WA, where I live, there's a university named _Western Washington University_. The sweatshirts say **WWU**. But _Western Washington University_ has 9 syllables, while _WWU_ has 7 -- not much of a saving -- and it's harder to say as well: /'dəbəlyu'dəbəlyu'yu/. I've found that the way people actually **pronounce** "WWU" is _Western_. Me, I just say /'wu'wu/; everybody understands what I mean.

Comment: I believe it was Douglas Adams who once observed that "www" (as in World Wide Web) takes _three times_ as many syllables to say as the phrase it abbreviates.

Comment: @CurtisH. Yet no-one says "Triple-W".

Comment: @fmark Ah, but there is the W3C.

Comment: Would you say this is related to the (BrE specific, I think) practice of reading out repeated digits in phone numbers using double or triple?

Comment: @congusbongus Yes, I would say it's related.

Comment: @Curtis !  I was going to make exactly the same comment  :)  The quote, which is I believe from his book "last chance to see", is, I think, "The World Wide Web is the only thing I know of whose shortened form takes three times longer to say than what it's short for." (note FWIW that the source for the quote, given on wikipedia currently, is simply wrong)

Comment: Don't forget the similar case: where we substitute letters with a number of letters that have been replaced. e.g. i18n and l10n.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 - For the benefit of visitors to this site who aren't programmers (what are the odds?), _i18n_ stands for "internationalization", while _l10n_ stands for "localization"; they describe different aspects of making a particular program/web page/app accessible to users from different languages/parts of the world.

Comment: Wrt WWW: Let's not forget the wobblies in the Industrial Workers of the World.  Supposedly the nickname came from immigrant members (and most were immigrants) pronouncing "IWW" as "eye wobbily wobbily" or similar.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is a word for a numeric acronym; after-all, anacronym is a word for "An acronym the original meaning of which is not known to most English speakers"

[Numeronym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeronym)

[Acronym types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialism#Comparing_a_few_examples_of_each_type)

Comment: +1 because a numeronym is very close.  This is an acronym or word that includes the number itself.  W3C for World Wide Web Consortium.  I don't know that it totally explains the practice of *reading* the acronym aloud in that manner.

Comment: This is a fantastic question, and "numeronym" is an interesting answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The term is just that Triple-A this is an **alias** for the AAA.  The trick to make it memorable can vary.  There apparently isn't much reason to talk about the concepts behind coining new terms for things to the extent that common language needs to invent a bucket load of specific terms and remember them.

After all, we invented "AAA" in the first place to avoid remembering the organization's name!